# NVD3 Line Plus Bar Chart X-Axis Ticks wrong alignment

Tags: date, line, bar-chart, nvd3.js

The X-Axis ticks are not aligned with the bars and lines in the chart. Where as the lines and bars are together aligned. My code and the graph here:
https://plnkr.co/edit/ar11Ww4Bdwb2zm2FxeOx?p=preview

In the actual project in my system the x-axis values are in the form of 'YYYY-mm-dd'which is converted to utc time format and given to the chart and while displaying it I used the

`xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {
   console.log(d);
   return d3.time.format('%Y-%m')(new Date(d))
 });`

function to display it.

I tried to force the number of ticks to be same as the number of bars using `xAxis.ticks()` function, but that did not help. How can I adjust this so that they can be aligned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try assigning tickValues :

```
chart.xAxis.tickValues(function(values) {return _.map(values[0].values, function(v) {
                    return new Date(v.x);
            })});
```